Zebra Label Printer (Gx430t) set printer configuration settings
I'm trying to change the printer settings of my Zebra GX430t usb printer so they persist for the entire time the printer is turned on. This is to avoid having to reload all printer settings every time windows decides its time to create a printer copy.
I'm using C# and the RawPrinterHelperclass.SendStringToPrinter().
I got this far:
^XA
^FX Speed and Darkness settings
^PR3
^MD27
^FX Label size settings
^LL240
^PW864
^FX Rotate 180
^POI
^FO50,50
^GB10,10,10^FS
^XZ

This prints a blank label, slower than normal, leading me to believe the zpl is working to change the configuration for this single label. This also tells me the SendStringToPrinter() is working properly since some commands do what they are supposed to. However, the next label prints fast (default) and is NOT rotated 180 (which is the main setting I need changed). I dont think I need the ^JUS command if I only need the settings to persist while the printer is turned on correct?
The label that I am printing is not in zpl, its a word doc.

Please note that Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned and read Help Center: AI policy. It is not permitted to use AI tools to generate or reword content that you post on Stack Overflow.

Word uses the Windows driver so you need to change the driver settings as well, otherwise no matter what settings you push to the printer, the driver settings will always overwrite the printer configuration.

Which there seems to be no good way of changing such printer specific settings like darkness and speed using c# ? It would be nice if the settings were just in plain text in the registry or something easy like that...
